# number of ways to move in a square matrix from source to destination

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Lets say we have a grid of size `n*n` (n<10). We have to move from source `(a,b)` to destination `(x,y)`. The grid is filled with `0's and 1's` where `0` means allowed path and `1` means blocked path. At each step, you can make a `chess piece king`s` move, ie., to any one of your surrounding 8 grids.

I have to get number of ways to reach destination from source. If you walk a path and retrace it backwards, its not to be counted (otherwise number of paths will be obvs infinite). Even if I don't have the exact number, its fine but a near approximation would work (ie. even an incorrect idea would be appreciated if it can at least give consistent results).

Any kind of idea, pseudo code, snippet in any language (preferably c++, java) would be of help.

PS: If a solution is such that has constraints on moves (like only right and up and r/u diagonal), but can be extended to other similar constraints, it would also help.

Comment: Have you tried DFS? Sounds like a problem that could have a straightforward DFS solution

Comment: The number of such paths is still infinite under your current description: you can cycle two adjacent cells however many times you want then continue on your way to the end. This doesn't retrace the whole path. You must either have a fixed number of steps you can make or specify that you can't visit the same cell twice. Which is it?

Comment: DFS would take forever. And how would I mark visited on nodes? I cannot count it by actually traversing, that is too troublesome and bad on complexity (even a naive question where you have r/d move constraints and you have to move from (0,0) to (n,n) has order of (n!) ways)

Comment: @IVlad  . . . I'm guessing the actual condition is that a path cannot contain a cell more than once.

Comment: @IVlad, yes. That is what I meant by retracing a path backwards... even a part of the path is not allowed to be retraced. Yes, you got that right (in any path you choose, one grid should be visited once)

Comment: Recurse whenever you have multiple options? With a 10x10 grid where a number of cells are blocked, the number of possibilities can't be too big.

Comment: @m69, But how do I make sure I am not visiting the same cell again? I'll be making a path tree in which each node will be having 8 children. Or do you suggest I do it one by one (I don't think that will match my time constraints)

Comment: You'd recurse on a copy of the board where you put a 1 on the square you are on, so gradually the board gets filled in the recursions.

Comment: @m69, that is my point. I don't want to retrace the path at all. It does not concern me. All I want is the number of ways. In 7 steps into the code, I'll be dealing with 8^7 possibilities, that is over 2e+6.

Comment: Well, you can never go back, so there are only ever 7 possibilities; and as the grid fills up with cells you've already visited, the number of possibilities will decrease. And a lot of paths will just lock themself in after a few moves. I don't think the number will becomes unmanageably large, but this of course also depends on how many cells are blocked at the start.

Comment: You see where I'm going?? 4x4 is a grid size that does not give 8 neighbors except on 4 cells. Try running it on 7x7. It will sure take a hell lot of time.

Comment: I'm actually planning to use this as a heuristic in a bot game. So, if possible, I'd like to keep this calculation easy, or else, every ply in itself will take a lot. That is why I said that even an approximation would work, as far as it is not too inconsistent.

Comment: What about the cells that are blocked from the start? They make a huge difference. Does it have to work for a completely open grid?

Comment: Yes, at the start of the game. But as the game progresses, more cells will be blocked.

Comment: Would you consider a solution that only counts paths made with down and right (and diagonally down and right if you want) moves as a good approximation?

Comment: @IVlad, I don't think it will work. As, what if source is (5,4) and destination is (1,2)? But, if I can extend it in all possible sides (like not just d/r, but u/r, u/l and d/l as well), it will be of great help.

Comment: @vish4071 yes, there is a solution that can be extended. Please add to your post that you will accept solutions for directions that cannot lead to a cycle. I'll post the solution.

Comment: Thanks all for help, esp. @m69 and IVIad for this discussion. I think I see a way now.

Comment: If you find a useful solution, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Brute-force results (now without the bug) for path from corner to corner across a 5x5 board: empty: 44,461,354 ; 1 corner blocked: 32,462,407 ; 2 corners: 16,091,085 ; side-mid: 7,746,574 ; center: 4,110,672 ; diagonally next to corner: 3,794,218 ; center + 2 corners: 1,475,908 ; center + diagonally next to corner: 432,112 ; center + 2x diagonally next to corner: 60,134 ; complete diagonal: 30,732. This suggests that the effect of blocked cells can be multiplied: e.g. center: 9%, 2 corners: 36%, center + 2 corners: 3.3%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to accept solutions for directions that cannot lead to a cycle, you can solve this with dynamic programming.

For example, if you can only go **down** and **right**:

```
d[i, j] = number of ways of reaching [i, j] from [1, 1]
```

We have:

```
d[1, 1] = 1
d[i, j] = d[i - 1, j] +        <- move down from (i - 1, j) to (i, j)
          d[i, j - 1]          <- move right from (i, j - 1) to (i, j)
```

**Note:** make sure to ignore invalid indexes.

To only move from `(a, b)` to `(x, y)`, you can imagine setting the top left corner of `d` to `(a, b)`, then computing up until `d[x - a + 1, y - b + 1]`.

In order to deal with blocked cells, simply set `d` to `0` for their position.

This can easily be extended to other pairs (or triples) of moves that cannot result in cycles. You can do it either by rotating your matrix and doing the same thing, or by adapting the formula slightly.

For example, for **up** and **right** you'd have:

```
d[i, j] = d[i + 1, j] + d[i, j - 1]
```

Which you'll need to compute by iterating the rows from bottom to top, not the usual top to bottom.

Note that some pairs of directions are the same as others: for example, the answer for **up** and **left** is the same as the one for **down** and **right**.

Comment: If I use this solution to let the source be source and every other 0-grid be destination, calculate a matrix of possible distances, then, taking every 0-grid as source and dest as dest, get another matrix, multiply corresponding values and add them, will it be a fine approximation? Also, it would be O(n^4) complex (as this approach is O(n^2)) i believe?

Comment: @vish4071 If you want to let every pair of free cells be the source and destination, you can do it like you said in `O(n^4)` or use two subtractions and an addition to find the answer in `O(1)` after computing the recurrence from `(1, 1)` to `(n, n)` once. I'm not sure what you mean by multiplying the corresponding values.

Comment: Say, source is (5,4) and dest is (1,2). Then, if there are 5 ways to reach a random cell starting from source (say, (3,4)) and 10 steps to reach dest from (3,4), I can assume we have 5*10, or 50 ways to reach dest. starting from source thru (3,4). Similarly for other grids. The, if I add them all, I'll get a good approximation. This is what I meant.

Comment: @vish4071 yes, multiplication will get you that, but this algorithm can get you the number of paths from `(5, 4)` to `(1, 2)` directly, so I'm not sure why you'd do that. What do you want to add? The number of paths between distinct sources and destinations? I don't understand why you'd do this either...

Comment: because actually I wanted the number of ways when all 8 directions of motion were allowed.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try both these methods and one that came to mind thru this discussion and compare the results. Thanks.

Comment: @vish4071 I understand that, but I can't say how adding and multiplying like that will fare. You might overcount. Try and see I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt an algorithm which could be more efficient than DFS by borrowing the idea from merge sort.

The idea is to mark an area, do an exhaustive search (another DFS) for it, and mark down the in-out vertices pairs and number of ways to do it for the area. This could avoid traversing again and again on the same area inducing the complexity.

However this could be clumsy to implement a neat pseudo code on a 10*10 board as it is not an exponential of 2, but cutting the board with any random number you like could do the job.

Comment: I'm not convinced this works. If I understand correctly, your basic idea is to cut the matrix in two, do brute force on the two sides, then multiply the number of paths found in the two halves. But this way, you won't be counting paths that keep switching between the two sides.

Comment: It is ok, since the contacting vertices should be counted too. The matrix does not necessary be cut to two: lets say if you have (a,b) = (3,3) and (x,y)=(7,7), you can have many different matrix segments as shown: http://imgur.com/YnhhkP7

The idea is more likely transfer computational power into memory requirement, and you can even do divide and conquer within the matrices easily too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to repeat a cell (graph node) the most nodes you can travel through will be 10x10, i.e. 100.

One approximation may be to consider going through all free cells in all it's combinations. That would make it (#free cells)!. At most 100!. But that is possibly a gross overestimation.

A more conservative approach and probably closer to the actual number is to use the two constraints we have, the 100 nodes and the 8 branching directions and make it 8^100. That number approximates branching 8 times each step until exhausting the 100 cells (if they are all free).

A slightly smaller approximation would not go back on itself so would only have 7 branching directions making it 7^100. This approximation would estimate 7^(#free cells).

An even smaller approximation that considers amount of blocked cells also for branching estimate could shrink the 7 by the percentage of blocked cells, i.e use (7 x #free_cells/100) ^ (#free_cells). This will definitely start underestimating once the number of blocked cells gets the exponent base close enough to (or smaller than) 1.

You don't state why you want this number. Hope these approaches help you.

Comment: But this does not consider blocked cells.

Comment: well you can use the average of free cells around free cells for the connectivity (instead of 8). That way the block cells are used for both constraints

Comment: I think the blocked cells have a much greater effect than their relative number would suggest; you'll have to try it out on smaller grids to come up with some kind of ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to code it in javascript to take advantage of JS functional programming capacities.

```
function out_bound(i,j,n) {
//returns true if coordinates (i,j) are out of bounds (n is the size of the grid)
  return (!((i<n)&&(i>=0)&&(j<n)&&(j>=0)));    
}    

function arrived(i,j,k,l) {
//returns true if the current position (i,j) is at the final position (k,l)
  return ((i===k)&&(j===l));    
}

function nb_path(i,j,k,l,grid) {
//returns the number of paths to go from (i,j) to (k,l) in the grid
  if (arrived(i,j,k,l)) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (out_bound(i,j,grid.length)) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (grid[i][j] === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    grid[i][j]=1;
    return nb_path(i,j+1,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i,j-1,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i+1,j,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i-1,j,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i+1,j+1,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i-1,j-1,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i+1,j-1,k,l,deepCopy(grid)) + nb_path(i-1,j+1,k,l,deepCopy(grid));
  }
}

// it works for the following toy-case (I have checked by hand)
var myGrid = [[0,0],[0,0]];
console.log("there are: "+nb_path(0,0,1,1,deepCopy(myGrid))+" possible paths");
```